# how to change relativelayout's background with each time pressing the butoon in android programming?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

this is my java code
i set relativelayout reference and make switch but i dont know how to work with it 
and i made rl variable 
what should i put in case ................;
thanks for who help me

```
private OnClickListener chavoshipicchangerlistener=new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        RelativeLayout relativlayout_ref = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
                        switch (rl) {
                        case relativlayout_ref :
                             relativlayout_ref.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mohsenchavoshitwo);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }



                    }
                };
```

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do? Do you have a bunch of background images and you want to switch from one to the next on every click? Or do you wanna set them randomly? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: i have a bunch of background images and i want to switch from one to the next on every click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gonna need a list of all possible backgrounds and an index to know which one is the next. I would probably do something like this:

```
private OnClickListener chavoshipicchangerlistener=new OnClickListener() {
    private final static List<Integer> backgrounds = new ArrayList<Integer>(){
        add(R.drawable.mohsenchavoshione);
        add(R.drawable.mohsenchavoshitwo);
        add(R.drawable.mohsenchavoshithree);
    };

    private int idx = 0;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RelativeLayout relativlayout_ref = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);

                    idx++;
                    if(idx >= backgrounds.size()){
                        idx = 0;
                    }

                    relativlayout_ref.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds.get(idx));
                }
            };
```

Comment: it gives me error on dot R.drawable.mohsenchavoshione the dot before mohsen chavoshi

Comment: What is the error? did you import the correct `R`?

Comment: yes,it gives me error on the . before mohsenchavoshi

Comment: 1. If you want people to be able to help you, you need to be more specific about the error you're getting. No one of us has a magic crystal ball where we can see the exact error. 2. This is a new problem. Mark the best response as answer (if it answered your original question) and create a new question for the new problem.

Comment: you gave me the code but it made a error and now i put the link of the error image see it and answer me thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the selector to change colors according to states. Here is all the info you will need http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html I hope this helps.

Comment: Iranian people are prohibited from this link

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this way

1. create an array of drawable resources.
2. create a global indexvariable and update with each click and if it reaches end of the array 
   go back to zero element.

   int indexVariable=0;
       int drawableArray[];
       oncreate() 
       {
           drawableArray=new int[3];
           drawableArray[0]=R.drawable.bg1;
           drawableArray[1]=R.drawable.bg2;
           drawableArray[2]=R.drawable.bg3;

   ```
       button.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawableArray[indexVariable]);

                    indexVariable++;
                    if(indexVariable>=drawableArray.length)
                      indexVariable=0; // loopback

       });

   }
   ```